# How to optimize Magento 2 blocks cache lifetime? TTL

Tags: php, caching, block, magento2, ttl

Are there any ready-to-use settings for Magento 2 blocks cache lifetime for high load servers?

I mean for each block type: sidebars, headers, footers, categories, products etc.

For example, what values should be set for a header-block, content-block, sidebar-block? 60 seconds, 300 seconds or 360000 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

By default every block that is cached has a cache lifetime (see `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::getCacheLifetime`).
Those will be either refreshed by invalidation calls or when you manually clean/flush the cache (cli or admin backend).

More information:

[Magento 2 Dev Guide: Manage the Cache](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html)

[How the full page works in Magento 2](https://inviqa.com/blog/how-full-page-cache-works-magento-2)

Comment: Yes. That's right. I am aware of that but the question is if there are any specific recommended sets of options used by Magento developers for each block. I mean ready-to-use-specific-values to improve efficiency. For example, what values can be set for a header-block, content-block, sidebar-block? 60 seconds, 300 seconds or 360000 seconds?

Comment: For this I dont have any information. I can say, that we are running our store with the default cache settings and a redis cache and it works fine. Magento 2 performance is improved in every release so I think sticking to the defaults in caching is fine.